# FFmpeg progress bar in Visual C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ffmpeg

I'm converting video file using ffmpeg. I need to show converting progress status on a progress bar. 
I'm using visual C++. how can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg library or using ffmpeg.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the conversion in a worker thread and the progressbar must be created by a UI-thread. If you choose to convert the video in the main (UI-thread), you should call CProgressBar::UpdateWindow() every now and than. You could call time() and determine if it is time to redraw the progresss bar. This way, you don't put too much load on the CPU. Drawing it every time the video conversion calls the call back function, makes your program really slow.